# Unable to replace characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following url as a string:

```
var fb= "https://www.facebook.com/XYZ"
```

I want to remove https://www.facebook.com and display only /XYZ.

I tried alert(fb.replace("facebook.com","")); alert(fb.substring('facebook.com'.length));
but it didn`t help

Tried code :

```
alert(fb.replace("facebook.com",""));
alert(fb.substring('facebook.com'.length));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You tried something?

Comment: alert(fb.replace("https://www.facebook.com",""));
      alert(fb.substring('https://www.facebook.com'.length));

Comment: If you are just wondering about down votes you got, it is because, you haven't mentioned your tried code initially. Next time, please add your tried code along with question.

Comment: @RajendraGupta - Please see my answer for your problem.

Comment: @MuhammadQasim you copied original ans.. atleast have courtesy to upvote the originals..

Comment: @user7417866 - I have not copied anything. I have answered myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to get the last part of the given url.

This will do.

```
alert(fb.substr(fb.lastIndexOf('/')));
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b0nnoqy0/)

Answer (score 2):

This is simple. Try the following:

```
var fb="https://www.facebook.com/XYZ";    
var x = fb.substr(fb.lastIndexOf("/"), fb.length);
```

Now x has got the final result in x as

> "/XYZ"

Comment: Yeah i thought he wants only xyz without a slash. Thanks anyways

Comment: @RajendraGupta - Its my pleasure :) Always there to help you guus. Please upvote and mark answer to help others as well..:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var fb = https://www.facebook.com/XYZ
fb = fb .substr(fb.indexOf("/") + 1); // Contains XYZ //
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fb="https://www.facebook.com/XYZ";

var res = fb.replace("https://www.facebook.com", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#replace` and a regular expression (which allows you to add flexibility in the kind of URLs you accept, like `http` / `https` or `www.facebook.com` / `facebook.com`).

```js
var fb = 'https://www.facebook.com/XYZ'

console.log(
  fb.replace(/^https?:\/\/(?:www.)?facebook.com(?=\/)/, '') //=> '/XYZ'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fb="https://www.facebook.com/XYZ"
fb.split('/')[3];
alert(fb.split('/')[3])
</script>
```

it working please try